# connect EHOSTUNREACH 172.24.0.2:27017 docker-compose

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-command

I am currently unable to connect to mongo when I run docker-compose, I keep on getting the  error below

```
connect EHOSTUNREACH 172.25.0.2:27017
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3.4"
services: 
    app:
        container_name: checki
        restart: always
        build:
          context: .
          network: host
        ports: 
          - "3000:9000"
        links: 
          - mongo
    mongo:
        container_name: mongo
        image: mongo
        volumes:
          - ./data:/data/db
        ports: 
          - "27018:27017"
```

and my db connection string is like this

```
"mongodb://mongo:27017/checki"
```

Please assist

Comment: If you wait 30-60 seconds, does it start up?  (Do you see MongoDB startup logs in the `docker-compose up` output after the application failure?)

Comment: I can see the logs 
`mongo    | {"t":{"$date":"2021-05-12T15:42:40.391+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23016,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}}`
it does not startup at all